# Tweaking Floyd-Warshall Algorithm to detect cycles

Tags: algorithms, graphs, greedy-algorithms, weighted-graphs

Cheers, I am trying to solve the problem of minimum length cycle in a graph, and I came across a solution that suggested that I should tweak the Floyd-Warshall algorithm to solve that. It stated that instead of setting `path[i][i] = 0` I should instead set `path[i][i] = INFINITY`, but I don't exactly understand why that is the case! I find that the main diagonal of the array used by Floyd-Warshall does not change, so how can it help me to see the path of the cycle? I understand that the generated array of the algorithm helps me find the shortest path of a pair. e.g. `path[i][j]` gives me the shortest path from *i* to *j* but, although the intuition stays the same, I see that nothing changes, and I can't take the desired result.

I even tried visualing the process, as seen [here](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/%7Egalles/visualization/Floyd.html). I generated the graph below:

[image: graph]

but as you can see, although the diagonal is initialized with infinity, it does not get changed, even though the graph clearly has cycles. Can anyone explain what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

If you let it, running the algorithm will produce, in `path[i][i]`, the length of the shortest path from node `i` to `i`. The length of the shortest cycle will be the smallest value on the diagonal. This requires

- updating `path[i][i]`, instead of skipping it, like [that visualization](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/%7Egalles/visualization/Floyd.html) does;
- initializing `path[i][i]` with the actual cost of going from that node to itself in one step: the cost of a self-loop, or if there is no self-loop, infinity.

Initializing the diagonal with 0s will leave it at all 0s, even when you don't skip updating it.